# Oracle: Reference aliased sub-queries in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, nested, subquery, alias, where-clause

I'd like to address some fairly complex sub-queries in my outmost `WHERE`-clause. I'm aware of the fact that I **cannot** reference the aliased column by its name, since the `SELECT`-clause is evaluated **after** the `WHERE`-clause.

*So this will **not** work:*

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       (SELECT ComplexStuff FROM ComplexTables) ComplexColumn
FROM Table
WHERE ComplexColumn LIKE '%Foobar%';
```

I'm also aware of the alternatives, namels repeating the sub-query in the `WHERE`-clause or wrapping my entire `SELECT`-statement.

*Option 1*:

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       (SELECT ComplexStuff FROM ComplexTables) ComplexColumn
FROM Table
WHERE (SELECT ComplexStuff FROM ComplexTables) LIKE '%Foobar%';
```

*Option 2:*

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT FirstName,
          LastName,
          (SELECT ComplexStuff FROM ComplexTables) ComplexColumn
  FROM Table)
WHERE ComplexColumn LIKE '%Foobar%';
```

The first solution is not very maintainable, because I have to repeat every sub-query and this is a bad habit, especially if the sub-queries are very complex.

My question is: How efficient is the second solution in terms of performance? If I'm not mistaken, the wrapped query will always return **all** entries and they will not be filtered unless the outmost `WHERE`-clause is applied. Do I have to worry about this or do database optimizers manage to push down the predicates into the inner queries as much as possible? I'm on Oracle, if this is relevant.

Are there any other downsides, when I use the second option, have a lot of data and want my query to perform well?

Comment: Oracle execution plan can give you some useful information about the performance of both queries.

Comment: It is a call that you have to take bearing in mind your table size and index options on the complexstuff query. It is good to use option 1 if the table size is too big, that it restricts selection of all data. Likewise, option 2 is better if you have limited number of data in the table or partitioned tables with proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.FirstName,
   a.LastName,
   b.ComplexColumn
FROM Table a,
    (SELECT ComplexStuff ComplexColumn FROM ComplexTables) b
WHERE b.ComplexColumn LIKE '%Foobar%'
```